# Substring with converting to numeric proc sql

Tags: sas

My variable is '123 - How to convert char with substring'.
The result I need to get is a variable 123 with numeric type.
`Substring(myvariable,1,3)`  How to get it numeric? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
my_var_numeric = input(substr(my_var, 1, 3), 8.);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option. This one will keep only numbers regardless of its length or position in the string.

```
data w;
string =  '1230 - How to convert char with substring';
number = input(compress(string,'0123456789','k'),best.);
output;
run;
```